# Integrating facebook, linkedin , twitter to android app

Tags: android, social-media

is it advisable to use a single sdk to integrate facebook, linkedin, twitter to android app or to use conventionally provided libraries by these social media platforms?

if there is a single sdk please recommend a good solution for this !!
otherwise please recommend some good tutorials to seamlessly integrate social media platforms to android!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use the 3 different SDK's for each social network.[This](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/) should facilitate your work a lot in regards of importing them.